# Can't Clear ArrayList everytime the method runs

Tags: java, android, arraylist

```
public void incorrectlive() {
ArrayList<String> Wor = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> Def = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.WW);

    Scanner sc, sc2;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        Wor.clear();
        Def.clear();
        sc = new Scanner(openFileInput("w.txt"));
        sc2 = new Scanner(openFileInput("d.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine() && sc2.hasNextLine()) {
            Q = sc.nextLine();
            Wor.add(Q);
            D = sc2.nextLine();
            Def.add(D);
            count++;
        }
        sc.close();
        sc2.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        String wr = Wor.get(i);
        String dr = Def.get(i);
        addword(wr, dr, layout);
    }
}
```

i want to clear the contents of `Wor` & `Def` every time `incorrectlive()` runs but it isn't happening. There are no errors in Catlog, it only keeps on re adding the older ones which causes repeatations

Comment: What do you mean by *"it isn't happening"*? Why do you even call `clear()`? You just created the lists, so they are already empty.

Comment: but they seem to have data even after initializing it in the method which should make them empty but thats not the case

Comment: Perhaps it is whatever `addword` adds to that needs to be cleared, e.g. add call to `clearwords` before that `for` loop?

Comment: And why do you use "Android" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO i found the solution...the problem was with the files which were used... so i flushed them using PrintStream. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your clear(); methods outside of your try/catch block...

Your program may also have a logic error depending on the context of which you called this method. Anything using the **static** keyword may cause some issues.

Comment: Thanks for the support though, and welcome to the community! Be safe from some rude people they will demoralize  you while answering your problems ;)